# GODOT 4 cuts off pixel in pixelart

Tags: sprite, pixel, godot4

I converted a project from godot 3.5 to godot 4.2.1 and changed texture import from linear to nearest, so it is pixel art. In the editor it works fine, but for some reason, it is doing some weird things when startet.

It cuts of pixels.

I think it is because of some pixel snap, I turned it of in the settings, it does not change anything :(

[image: See how new game is cut off and strangly gets white on top]

[image: this is how it should look]

Comment: Are these sprite2D or control elements? If its the second, you could try to set a bigger min size. Maybe it's calculated wrong